# ajax output in textbox is not available in post method of submit

Tags: php, ajax

I have a select dropdown, from that I'm calling an ajax function onchange event. Posting the result in a text input. This much is working perfectly. But when I submit the form the text input value is not submitting.

This is the ajax code. teachername dowpdown and teachercode text input

```
    $("#teachername").change(function(){ 
      var name = $(this).val(); 
      var dataString = "name="+name;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "get-teachercode.php",
        data: dataString, 
        success: function(result){ 
         $("#teachercode").val(result); 
        }
      });

 });
```

this is the form

```
 <form action="insert-assign-classes.php" method="post">
 <select class="form-control" name="teachername" id="teachername" required>
 </select>
 <input type="text" disabled style="background-color:#fff;" class="form-control" name="teachercode" id="teachercode" required>
```

getting the value in insert-assign-classes.php file.

```
$teachercode= $_POST['teachercode'];//not working
```

Comment: do you have the `$teachercode= $_POST['teachercode']` inside ur class or inside the `get-teachercode.php`?

Comment: @RamondeVries yes

Comment: I have solve the problem just need to replace "disabled" with  readonly. I don't know why but the code is working fine now. I tried the disable property again and its not working. But with readonly its working. My bad. Should I delete the question?

Comment: i think it's fine to let it stay here, just edit it showing what you fix was for this problem